# Single DB trip vs Multiple DB trips

Tags: android, sqlite, list

This could have been asked way before, I just don't know how to call it that's why its kinda difficult to find a finite answer.

Anyway, I am currently developing an Android application and utilizing SQLite as my data store. I just want to make this inquiry, which one is suppose to do better between the two below;

Single Trip to DB (Bulk Result) vs Multiple Trips to DB (Chunk Result)

Both Bulk Result and Chunk Results will be stored in a List.

Say for this scenario I have 15 records with 3 groups such as

```
App - IsFirstRun, IsNew, DatePurchased, etc..
User - Username, Password, Birthdate, Locale, etc..
License - Mode, Writes, Log, History, etc..
```

Which looks like this;

```
Group    Field        Value
App      IsFirstRun   N
App      IsNew        Y
App      DatePurchased
User     Username     Hello
User     Password     World
User     Birthdate    02/24/1950
Lic      Mode         F
Lic      Writes       200
```

Bulk will return all fields in one trip while Chunk will return all fields within 3 trips.

Such as Bulk;

```
userPrefValues = db.getCategoryValues2("USER_PREFS");

App      IsFirstRun   N
App      IsNew        Y
App      DatePurchased
User     Username     Hello
User     Password     World
User     Birthdate    02/24/1950
Lic      Mode         F
Lic      Writes       200
```

Chunks;

```
userPrefValues = db.getCategoryValues2("USER_1");
userPref2Values = db.getCategoryValues2("USER_2");
userPref3Values = db.getCategoryValues2("USER_3");

App      IsFirstRun   N
App      IsNew        Y
App      DatePurchased

User     Username     Hello
User     Password     World
User     Birthdate    02/24/1950

Lic      Mode         F
Lic      Writes       200
```

And both result sets would be iterated using a loop (as usual),

Initially, looking at it I could say I have better control with the multi-trips because of smaller datasize return, I want to know what others think and how they approach such scenario/situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my naive algorithm:

1. Small data size => Fewer trips, get more data and hold it in memory. Since the data is small, memory constraint shouldn't be a big problem.
2. Large data size => More trips with small data each time as needed. Since data is large, memory constraint will be a problem.

So basically, it comes down to how much memory your app has and the amount of data your application uses.

Answer (score 0):

For so few values, neither performance nor memory usage will be of any concern.

Use whatever method is easiest to handle in your code.
(Even one query execution per value would be possible.)